# Is it possible to use Lightning Data Services \ <force:recordData without sharing rules \ field level security?

Tags: field-level-security, sharing-rule, lightning-data-service, force-recorddata

It is possible to declare a Apex controller class as

```
public without sharing class noSharing { }
```

Is it possible to use Lightning Data Services

```
<force:recordData
```

Without sharing \ field level security?

Because I am getting this error:

> You don't have access to this record. Ask your administrator for help or to request access.

When I use Lightning Data Services on a publicly available Salesforce community page.

Comment: Maybe there is a sharing design problem, if you are trying to show record via your custom component, which (record) isn't visible to the user ?

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskiy I think it's because the page is on a publicly available page.

Comment: @Robs from when is LDS available for communities?

Comment: @RedDevil it works for communities now. See [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_considerations.htm)

Comment: Can we get an idea going on overriding visibility, please? This is a good feature to have!

Answer (score 2):

Lightning components don’t automatically enforce CRUD and FLS when you reference objects or retrieve the objects from an Apex controller. This means that the framework continues to display records and fields for which users don’t have CRUD access and FLS visibility. You must manually enforce CRUD and FLS in your Apex controllers.

But when it comes to [Lightning Data Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service.htm) it handles sharing rules and field-level security for you. So if you want it not to enforce these rules you will have to go for custom code in place of LDS.